# Why should you use theme(), rather than calling the theme functions directly?

Tags: theming

Why should you use `theme()`, rather than calling the theme functions directly?

```
theme('box', $title, drupal_get_form('comment_form', $edit, $title));
```

Why doesn't the code call the theme function directly, as in the following code?

```
theme_box($title, drupal_get_form('comment_form', $edit, $title));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use the theme() function for the override system to work. For example, your theme may override the theme function for a module, or a template (.tpl.php) file might be used instead.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/457740 explains what's meant by theme overriding. Overriding is an important feature because it's the magic that allows customizing the look & feel of a site.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you made, when you call `theme_box()` you are calling a specific function; when you are calling `theme('box')`, the function is calling a function that normally is`theme_box()`, but if a module implements [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) using the following code, the function being called is `theme_mymodule_box()`.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  // Kill the next/previous forum topic navigation links.
  if (!empty($theme_registry['box'])) {
      $theme_registry['box']['function'] = 'theme_mymodule_box';
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that in Drupal 7 every theme function has a preprocess function, not just the theme functions using a template file. This means that, in few cases, it is not necessary to override a theme function. If the code just need to change the content of a variable passed to the theme function, using a preprocess function is what should be done in Drupal 7.